# How can I change what URL the ASP.NET SPA Proxy directs to once the proxy is online?

Tags: asp.net, proxy, single-page-application, startup, vite

In Visual Studio 2022, in the Debug Options there is a way to change the URL that initially loads when you Debug a web application.

However, when using SPA in .net 6.0, the page that initially loads must be the base page, which waits for the SPA Proxy to be online, and then redirects to the SPA Proxy port to load your app when the proxy is ready.

What I'm wondering is if there's any way to set which page this will redirect to, similar to  how before using a SPA proxy I could set the debug launch URL to be different from the base `/` page.

The bundler I am using is Vite, and I have tried using the vite server "open" option to select a URL to open when the server launches.  Unfortunately since this is separate from asp.net's proxy logic, they both open.  The whole point is I'm trying to avoid loading the base `/` page.

I have tried modifying the .csproj file so that the `SpaProxyServerUrl` doesn't just have a port but has a full url, aka from `<SpaProxyServerUrl>https://localhost:44466</SpaProxyServerUrl>` to `<SpaProxyServerUrl>https://localhost:44466/Developer</SpaProxyServerUrl>`, but when I do this the spa proxy doesn't launch at all, and the index.html file doesn't load (which is configured in Program.cs with `app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");`

Is there a setting I'm missing somewhere?  Or does anyone have any ideas on how I can accomplish this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else is having the same problem in the future, I was able to get it to work.  Strangely for some reason the spa proxy wouldn't let me load my base page (localhost:44366) and load the spa proxy and redirect to localhost:44466/Developer.

However, it worked when *both sides* were configured to use the same endpoint.

So I changed the debug launch settings to load localhost:44366/Developer and also changed the .csproj's SpaProxyServerUrl to localhost:44466/Developer and then it worked.

No clue why it's setup this way but this change worked for me with .net 6